# JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb

How could I solve this?

I'm trying some Java code from a textbook (my first ever JAXB practice) in Eclipse.

I get the following error at runtime:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException:
> Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or
> classpath.
>
> - with linked exception: [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]     at
>   javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:278)  at
>   javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:421)     at
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)  at
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)  at
>   clasesjaxb.Ejemplo1_JAXB.main(Ejemplo1_JAXB.java:31) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
>   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
>   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>   at
>   javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122)
>   at
>   javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155)
>   at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:276)
>   ... 4 more

I needed to add the jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar to the project classpath in order to the project classes to compile:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDRzi.png)

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: JAXB is not included anymore in newer versions of Java, so it's expected that you have to add the API and an implementation JAR to the classpath if you're using a current Java version. See [my blog post](https://jesperdj.com/2018/09/30/jaxb-on-java-9-10-11-and-beyond/) for details.

Comment: it seems that the EclipseLink MOXy option solved the problem

Comment: The problem was that you added the API, but not an implementation. That's the case for most APIs of JEE / Jakarta EE. MOXy is a JAXB implementation, that's why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that error was solved following "Specifying the EclipseLink MOXy Runtime" instructions at [https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics](https://The%20error%20was%20solved%20following%20%22Specifying%20the%20EclipseLink%20MOXy%20Runtime%22%20instructions%20at%20https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics%20First%20adding)

1. adding eclipselink.jar to the project classpath
2. adding a jaxb.properties file at the package location with this content: "javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory"